# Too many indexers with iloc

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a data frame (df) which looks like this 
[image]

i am trying to get Week1 to Week3 sales for year 1950 to 1952. i am able to achieve this by loc using the below code

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[:,idx[:,1950:1952,'Week1':'Week3']]
```

**Result:**
[image]

but when i am trying to do it through iloc i am getting too many indexers error. I am using this code:

```
df.iloc[:,idx[:,:4,:4]]
```

why is it failing for iloc but working for loc?

below is the columns value of my data frame.

```
df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[['Sale'], [1950, 1951, 1952, 1953], ['Week1', 'Week2', 'Week3', 'Week4']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]],
       names=[None, 'Year', 'Week'])
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the input dataframe?